# JavaFX XYChart High frequency refresh

Tags: javafx, chartfx

I try to combine Chart-FX in https://github.com/GSI-CS-CO/chart-fx and TableView in JavaFX into one interface to meet my requirements. At present, I have written a demo to realize it. But now I find that when the number of points of the DataSet in the chart is getting more and more, it will block the UI thread and cause the refresh of the TableView to become stagnant. Moreover, my refresh frequency is at the millisecond level (refresh the table every 5ms and refresh the accumulated data to the chart every second). I have tried many methods. First of all, platform. runLater is not an option, because the refresh rate is too high and it will jam the UI thread. Then I try to replace the runLater with a service, which obviously reduces the memory usage. However, the problem of blocking when Chart and TableView refresh at the same time has not been solved. Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

The code is as follows:

```
package de.gsi.chart.samples;

import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import de.gsi.chart.plugins.DataPointTooltip;
import de.gsi.chart.plugins.TableViewer;
import de.gsi.chart.plugins.Zoomer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import de.gsi.chart.XYChart;
import de.gsi.chart.axes.spi.DefaultNumericAxis;
import de.gsi.chart.axes.spi.format.DefaultTimeFormatter;
import de.gsi.chart.plugins.EditAxis;
import de.gsi.chart.renderer.ErrorStyle;
import de.gsi.chart.renderer.datareduction.DefaultDataReducer;
import de.gsi.chart.renderer.spi.ErrorDataSetRenderer;
import de.gsi.chart.ui.ProfilerInfoBox;
import de.gsi.chart.ui.ProfilerInfoBox.DebugLevel;
import de.gsi.chart.ui.geometry.Side;
import de.gsi.dataset.event.AddedDataEvent;
import de.gsi.dataset.spi.CircularDoubleErrorDataSet;
import de.gsi.dataset.utils.ProcessingProfiler;

/**
 * @author rstein
 */
public class RollingBufferSample extends Application {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RollingBufferSample.class);
    public static final int DEBUG_UPDATE_RATE = 5000;
    // 0: just drop points that are drawn on the same pixel '3' points need to be at least 3 pixel apart to be drawn
    protected static final int MIN_PIXEL_DISTANCE = 0;
    public static int N_SAMPLES = 30; // default: 1000000
    public static int UPDATE_PERIOD = 1000; // [ms]
    public static int BUFFER_CAPACITY = 50000; // 750 samples @ 25 Hz <-> 30 s
    public final CircularDoubleErrorDataSet rollingBufferDipoleCurrent = new CircularDoubleErrorDataSet(
            "dipole current [A]", RollingBufferSample.BUFFER_CAPACITY);
    public final CircularDoubleErrorDataSet rollingBufferBeamIntensity = new CircularDoubleErrorDataSet(
            "beam intensity [ppp-1]", RollingBufferSample.BUFFER_CAPACITY);
    public final CircularDoubleErrorDataSet rollingBufferBeamIntensity2 = new CircularDoubleErrorDataSet(
            "beam intensity [ppp-2]", RollingBufferSample.BUFFER_CAPACITY);
    public final CircularDoubleErrorDataSet rollingBufferBeamIntensity3 = new CircularDoubleErrorDataSet(
            "beam intensity [ppp-3]", RollingBufferSample.BUFFER_CAPACITY);
    public final CircularDoubleErrorDataSet rollingBufferBeamIntensity4 = new CircularDoubleErrorDataSet(
            "beam intensity [ppp-4]", RollingBufferSample.BUFFER_CAPACITY);
    public final CircularDoubleErrorDataSet rollingBufferBeamIntensity5 = new CircularDoubleErrorDataSet(
            "beam intensity [ppp-5]", RollingBufferSample.BUFFER_CAPACITY);
    public final CircularDoubleErrorDataSet rollingBufferBeamIntensity6 = new CircularDoubleErrorDataSet(
            "beam intensity [ppp-6]", RollingBufferSample.BUFFER_CAPACITY);
    public final CircularDoubleErrorDataSet rollingBufferBeamIntensity7 = new CircularDoubleErrorDataSet(
            "beam intensity [ppp-7]", RollingBufferSample.BUFFER_CAPACITY);
    public final CircularDoubleErrorDataSet rollingBufferBeamIntensity8 = new CircularDoubleErrorDataSet(
            "beam intensity [ppp-8]", RollingBufferSample.BUFFER_CAPACITY);
    public final CircularDoubleErrorDataSet rollingBufferBeamIntensity9 = new CircularDoubleErrorDataSet(
            "beam intensity [ppp-9]", RollingBufferSample.BUFFER_CAPACITY);
    public final CircularDoubleErrorDataSet rollingBufferBeamIntensity10 = new CircularDoubleErrorDataSet(
            "beam intensity [ppp-10]", RollingBufferSample.BUFFER_CAPACITY);
    private final ErrorDataSetRenderer beamIntensityRenderer = new ErrorDataSetRenderer();
    private final ErrorDataSetRenderer beamIntensityRenderer2 = new ErrorDataSetRenderer();
    private final ErrorDataSetRenderer beamIntensityRenderer3 = new ErrorDataSetRenderer();
    private final ErrorDataSetRenderer beamIntensityRenderer4 = new ErrorDataSetRenderer();
    private final ErrorDataSetRenderer beamIntensityRenderer5 = new ErrorDataSetRenderer();
    private final ErrorDataSetRenderer beamIntensityRenderer6 = new ErrorDataSetRenderer();
    private final ErrorDataSetRenderer beamIntensityRenderer7 = new ErrorDataSetRenderer();
    private final ErrorDataSetRenderer beamIntensityRenderer8 = new ErrorDataSetRenderer();
    private final ErrorDataSetRenderer beamIntensityRenderer9 = new ErrorDataSetRenderer();
    private final ErrorDataSetRenderer beamIntensityRenderer10 = new ErrorDataSetRenderer();
    private final ErrorDataSetRenderer dipoleCurrentRenderer = new ErrorDataSetRenderer();
    private final DefaultNumericAxis yAxis1 = new DefaultNumericAxis("beam intensity", "ppp");
    private final DefaultNumericAxis yAxis2 = new DefaultNumericAxis("dipole current", "A");
    protected Timer[] timer;
    private  int i=0;

    private void generateBeamIntensityData() {
        final long startTime = ProcessingProfiler.getTimeStamp();
        final double now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000.0 + 1;
        // N.B. '+1' to check for resolution

        if (rollingBufferBeamIntensity.getDataCount() == 0) {
            // suppress auto notification since we plan to add multiple data points
            // N.B. this is for illustration of the 'setAutoNotification(..)' functionality
            // one may use also the add(double[], double[], ...) method instead
            boolean oldState = rollingBufferBeamIntensity.autoNotification().getAndSet(false);
            for (int n = RollingBufferSample.N_SAMPLES; n >= 0; --n) {
                final double t = now - n * RollingBufferSample.UPDATE_PERIOD / 1000.0;
                final double y = 100 * RollingBufferSample.rampFunctionBeamIntensity(t);
                final double ey = 1;
                if(i<3500){
//                    rollingBufferBeamIntensity.add(t, (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                }
                i++;
                // N.B. update events suppressed by 'setAutoNotification(false)' above
            }
            rollingBufferBeamIntensity.autoNotification().set(oldState);
            // need to issue a separate update notification
            rollingBufferBeamIntensity.fireInvalidated(new AddedDataEvent(rollingBufferBeamIntensity));
        } else {
            final double t = now;
            final double y2 = 100 * RollingBufferSample.rampFunctionBeamIntensity(t);
            final double ey = 1;
            // single add automatically fires update event/update of chart
//            rollingBufferBeamIntensity.add(t, (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
        }

        ProcessingProfiler.getTimeDiff(startTime, "adding data into DataSet");
    }

    private void generateDipoleCurrentData() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        final long startTime = ProcessingProfiler.getTimeStamp();
        final double now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000.0 + 1; // N.B. '+1'
                // to check
                // for
                // resolution

        if (rollingBufferDipoleCurrent.getDataCount() == 0) {
            // suppress auto notification since we plan to add multiple data points
            // N.B. this is for illustration of the 'setAutoNotification(..)' functionality
            // one may use also the add(double[], double[], ...) method instead
            boolean oldState = rollingBufferDipoleCurrent.autoNotification().getAndSet(false);
            for (int n = RollingBufferSample.N_SAMPLES; n >= 0; --n) {
                final double t = now - n * RollingBufferSample.UPDATE_PERIOD / 1000.0;
                final double y = 25 * RollingBufferSample.rampFunctionDipoleCurrent(t);
                final double ey = 1;
                rollingBufferDipoleCurrent.add(t, (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                // N.B. update events suppressed by 'setAutoNotification(false)' above
            }
            rollingBufferDipoleCurrent.autoNotification().set(oldState);
            // need to issue a separate update notification
            rollingBufferDipoleCurrent.fireInvalidated(new AddedDataEvent(rollingBufferDipoleCurrent));
        } else {
            boolean oldState = rollingBufferDipoleCurrent.autoNotification().getAndSet(false);
            for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
                final double t = now;
                final double y = 25 * RollingBufferSample.rampFunctionDipoleCurrent(t);
                final double ey = 1;
                // single add automatically fires update event/update of chart
                rollingBufferBeamIntensity.add(System.currentTimeMillis(), (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                rollingBufferBeamIntensity2.add(System.currentTimeMillis(), (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                rollingBufferBeamIntensity3.add(System.currentTimeMillis(), (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                rollingBufferBeamIntensity4.add(System.currentTimeMillis(), (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                rollingBufferBeamIntensity5.add(System.currentTimeMillis(), (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                rollingBufferBeamIntensity6.add(System.currentTimeMillis(), (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                rollingBufferBeamIntensity7.add(System.currentTimeMillis(), (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                rollingBufferBeamIntensity8.add(System.currentTimeMillis(), (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                rollingBufferBeamIntensity9.add(System.currentTimeMillis(), (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                rollingBufferBeamIntensity10.add(System.currentTimeMillis(), (int)(Math.random()*1000), ey, ey);
                System.out.println("当前计数"+i++);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            rollingBufferDipoleCurrent.autoNotification().set(oldState);
            // need to issue a separate update notification
            rollingBufferDipoleCurrent.fireInvalidated(new AddedDataEvent(rollingBufferDipoleCurrent));
        }

        ProcessingProfiler.getTimeDiff(startTime, "adding data into DataSet");
    }

    private HBox getHeaderBar(Scene scene) {
        final Button newDataSet = new Button("new DataSet");
        newDataSet.setOnAction(evt -> {
//            getTask(0).run();
//            getTask(1).run();

            Service<Integer> service=new Service() {
                @Override
                protected Task createTask() {
                    return new Task() {
                        @Override
                        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                            int i=0;
                            while (true){
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                updateValue(i++);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
            service.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Integer> observable, Integer oldValue, Integer newValue) {
                        generateDipoleCurrentData();
                }
            });
            service.start();
        });

        final Button startTimer = new Button("timer");
        startTimer.setOnAction(evt -> {
            if (timer == null) {
                timer = new Timer[2];
                timer[0] = new Timer("sample-update-timer", true);
                rollingBufferBeamIntensity.reset();
                timer[0].scheduleAtFixedRate(getTask(0), 0, UPDATE_PERIOD);

                timer[1] = new Timer("sample-update-timer", true);
                rollingBufferDipoleCurrent.reset();
                timer[1].scheduleAtFixedRate(getTask(1), 0, UPDATE_PERIOD);
            } else {
                timer[0].cancel();
                timer[1].cancel();
                timer = null; // NOPMD
            }
        });

        // H-Spacer
        Region spacer = new Region();
        spacer.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);

        final ProfilerInfoBox profilerInfoBox = new ProfilerInfoBox(DEBUG_UPDATE_RATE);
        profilerInfoBox.setDebugLevel(DebugLevel.VERSION);

        return new HBox(newDataSet, startTimer, spacer, profilerInfoBox);
    }

    protected TimerTask getTask(final int updateItem) {
        return new TimerTask() {
            private int updateCount;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (updateItem == 0) {
                    generateBeamIntensityData();
                } else {
                    generateDipoleCurrentData();
                }

                if (updateCount % 20 == 0 && LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    LOGGER.atDebug().addArgument(updateCount).log("update iteration #{}");
                }
                updateCount++;
            }
        };
    }

    public BorderPane initComponents(Scene scene) {
        final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        generateBeamIntensityData();
        generateDipoleCurrentData();
        initErrorDataSetRenderer(beamIntensityRenderer);
        initErrorDataSetRenderer(beamIntensityRenderer2);
        initErrorDataSetRenderer(beamIntensityRenderer3);
        initErrorDataSetRenderer(beamIntensityRenderer4);
        initErrorDataSetRenderer(beamIntensityRenderer5);
        initErrorDataSetRenderer(beamIntensityRenderer6);
        initErrorDataSetRenderer(beamIntensityRenderer7);
        initErrorDataSetRenderer(beamIntensityRenderer8);
        initErrorDataSetRenderer(beamIntensityRenderer9);
        initErrorDataSetRenderer(beamIntensityRenderer10);
        initErrorDataSetRenderer(dipoleCurrentRenderer);

        final DefaultNumericAxis xAxis1 = new DefaultNumericAxis("time");
        xAxis1.setAutoRangeRounding(false);
        xAxis1.setTickLabelRotation(45);
        xAxis1.setMinorTickCount(30);
        xAxis1.invertAxis(false);
        xAxis1.setTimeAxis(true);
        yAxis2.setSide(Side.RIGHT);
        yAxis2.setAnimated(false);
        // N.B. it's important to set secondary axis on the 2nd renderer before
        // adding the renderer to the chart
        dipoleCurrentRenderer.getAxes().add(yAxis2);

        final XYChart chart = new XYChart(xAxis1, yAxis1);
        chart.legendVisibleProperty().set(true);
        chart.setAnimated(false);
        chart.getRenderers().set(0, beamIntensityRenderer);
//        chart.getRenderers().add(beamIntensityRenderer2);
//        chart.getRenderers().add(beamIntensityRenderer3);
//        chart.getRenderers().add(beamIntensityRenderer4);
//        chart.getRenderers().add(beamIntensityRenderer5);
//        chart.getRenderers().add(beamIntensityRenderer6);
//        chart.getRenderers().add(beamIntensityRenderer7);
//        chart.getRenderers().add(beamIntensityRenderer8);
//        chart.getRenderers().add(beamIntensityRenderer9);
//        chart.getRenderers().add(beamIntensityRenderer10);
        chart.getPlugins().add(new EditAxis());
        chart.getPlugins().add(new DataPointTooltip());
        chart.getPlugins().add(new Zoomer());//工具栏
        chart.getPlugins().add(new TableViewer());

        beamIntensityRenderer.getDatasets().add(rollingBufferBeamIntensity);
        beamIntensityRenderer.getDatasets().add(rollingBufferBeamIntensity2);
        beamIntensityRenderer.getDatasets().add(rollingBufferBeamIntensity3);
        beamIntensityRenderer.getDatasets().add(rollingBufferBeamIntensity4);
        beamIntensityRenderer.getDatasets().add(rollingBufferBeamIntensity5);
        beamIntensityRenderer.getDatasets().add(rollingBufferBeamIntensity6);
        beamIntensityRenderer.getDatasets().add(rollingBufferBeamIntensity7);
        beamIntensityRenderer.getDatasets().add(rollingBufferBeamIntensity8);
        beamIntensityRenderer.getDatasets().add(rollingBufferBeamIntensity9);
        beamIntensityRenderer.getDatasets().add(rollingBufferBeamIntensity10);
        dipoleCurrentRenderer.getDatasets().add(rollingBufferDipoleCurrent);

        // set localised time offset
        if (xAxis1.isTimeAxis() && xAxis1.getAxisLabelFormatter() instanceof DefaultTimeFormatter) {
            final DefaultTimeFormatter axisFormatter = (DefaultTimeFormatter) xAxis1.getAxisLabelFormatter();

            axisFormatter.setTimeZoneOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
            axisFormatter.setTimeZoneOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(5, 0));
        }

        yAxis1.setForceZeroInRange(true);
        yAxis2.setForceZeroInRange(true);
        yAxis1.setAutoRangeRounding(true);
        yAxis2.setAutoRangeRounding(true);

        // init menu bar
        root.setTop(getHeaderBar(scene));

        long startTime = ProcessingProfiler.getTimeStamp();
        ProcessingProfiler.getTimeDiff(startTime, "adding data to chart");

        startTime = ProcessingProfiler.getTimeStamp();
        root.setCenter(chart);
        TableView<Person> pane = getPane();
        root.setBottom(pane);

        ProcessingProfiler.getTimeDiff(startTime, "adding chart into StackPane");

        return root;
    }

    protected void initErrorDataSetRenderer(final ErrorDataSetRenderer eRenderer) {
        eRenderer.setErrorType(ErrorStyle.ERRORSURFACE);
        // for higher performance w/o error bars, enable this for comparing with
        // the standard JavaFX charting library (which does not support error
        // handling, etc.)
        eRenderer.setErrorType(ErrorStyle.NONE);
        eRenderer.setDashSize(RollingBufferSample.MIN_PIXEL_DISTANCE); // plot pixel-to-pixel distance
        eRenderer.setPointReduction(true);
        eRenderer.setDrawMarker(false);
        final DefaultDataReducer reductionAlgorithm = (DefaultDataReducer) eRenderer.getRendererDataReducer();
        reductionAlgorithm.setMinPointPixelDistance(RollingBufferSample.MIN_PIXEL_DISTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        ProcessingProfiler.setVerboseOutputState(true);
        ProcessingProfiler.setLoggerOutputState(true);
        ProcessingProfiler.setDebugState(false);

        final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1800, 1000);
        root.setCenter(initComponents(scene));

        final long startTime = ProcessingProfiler.getTimeStamp();
        primaryStage.setTitle(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(evt -> Platform.exit());
        primaryStage.show();
        ProcessingProfiler.getTimeDiff(startTime, "for showing");
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public static double rampFunctionBeamIntensity(final double t) {
        final int second = (int) Math.floor(t);
        final double subSecond = t - second;
        double offset = 0.3;
        final double y = (1 - 0.1 * subSecond) * 1e9;
        double gate = RollingBufferSample.square(2, subSecond - offset)
                      * RollingBufferSample.square(1, subSecond - offset);

        // every 5th cycle is a booster mode cycle
        if (second % 5 == 0) {
            offset = 0.1;
            gate = Math.pow(RollingBufferSample.square(3, subSecond - offset), 2);
        }

        if (gate <= 0 || subSecond < offset) {
            gate = 0;
        }

        return gate * y;
    }

    public static double rampFunctionDipoleCurrent(final double t) {
        final int second = (int) Math.floor(t);
        final double subSecond = t - second;
        double offset = 0.3;

        double y = 100 * RollingBufferSample.sine(1, subSecond - offset);

        // every 5th cycle is a booster mode cycle
        if (second % 5 == 0) {
            offset = 0.1;
            y = 100 * Math.pow(RollingBufferSample.sine(1.5, subSecond - offset), 2);
        }

        if (y <= 0 || subSecond < offset) {
            y = 0;
        }
        return y + 10;
    }

    private static double sine(final double frequency, final double t) {
        return Math.sin(2.0 * Math.PI * frequency * t);
    }

    private static double square(final double frequency, final double t) {
        final double sine = 100 * Math.sin(2.0 * Math.PI * frequency * t);
        final double squarePoint = Math.signum(sine);
        return squarePoint >= 0 ? squarePoint : 0.0;
    }

    ObservableList<Person> realTimeDataObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public TableView<Person> getPane(){
//创建一个表格来模仿实际业务刷新
            TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();

            TableColumn<Person, String> name = new TableColumn<>("Firstname");
            name.setPrefWidth(200);
            name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

            TableColumn<Person, String> lastName = new TableColumn<>("lastName");
            lastName.setPrefWidth(200);
            lastName.setCellValueFactory(person -> person.getValue().lastNameProperty());

            TableColumn<Person, String> email = new TableColumn<>("email");
            email.setPrefWidth(200);
            email.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));

            //noinspection unchecked
            tableView.getColumns().addAll(name, lastName, email);


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                Person person = new Person("firstName" + i, "lastName" + i, "email" + i);
                realTimeDataObservableList.add(person);
            }

            tableView.setItems(realTimeDataObservableList);

//创建一个service用来高频刷新表格
            Service<Integer> service = new Service<Integer>() {

                @Override
                protected Task<Integer> createTask() {

                    return new Task<Integer>() {

                        @Override
                        protected Integer call() throws Exception {

                            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {

                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);

                                updateValue(i);
                            }

                            return 1000000000;
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
//监听service的value属性更改
            service.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
//                try {
//                    Thread.sleep(100);
//                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
//                }
                for (Person person : realTimeDataObservableList) {

                    person.setFirstName("firstname" + newValue);
                    person.setLastName("lastname" + newValue);
                    person.setEmail("email" + newValue);

//                System.out.println("正在更新" + newValue);
                }
            });
            service.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
                    System.out.println(newValue);
                }
            });
            service.start();
            return tableView;
        }
        //tableview里面的工具类
    public static class Person {

        private final StringProperty firstName;
        private final StringProperty lastName;
        private final StringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String lName) {
            lastName.set(lName);
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String inMail) {
            email.set(inMail);
        }

        public StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return email;
        }  // if this method is commented out then the tableview will not refresh when the email is set.
    }
}``
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the __M__! That said: why do you use util.TimerTask? Typically, sticking to fx concurrency support should should be fine (and reduces complexity).

Comment: I wrote two implementations, the new DataSet button uses a Service, and the Timer button uses a TimerTask, but both of them have the same result, when the chart points are too many, the TableView refresh will be stalling

Comment: nobody wants to wade through tons of unrelated code - it's up to you to find the exact bottleneck, strip it down to a [mcve] to demonstrate what exactly is causing it. As mipa already mentioned in his answer: there is a limit that you can't overcome - and it makes not much sense to try for visualization ;)

Comment: First of all, Chart uses a third-party framework. To imitate the problems I encountered, this is not a simple demo, so all the codes in it are necessary. If my description is not clear, I can re-describe it

Comment: divide-and-conquer - that's the strategy to win :) You complain about the table not refreshing: so provide an example that does nothing but modify the table data quickly (but not more quickly than the human mind can follow it ;) - no external lib needed, simulate it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one of the most important details. You have to click on the NewDataSet button to see the effect. The more points you have on the isogram, the more obvious it will be

Answer (score 2):

You should think about reducing your data update rate. It just does not make sense to update at 5 ms if your monitor update rate is just 16.7 ms corresponding to 60 Hz. Even 60 Hz may be too much for a human eye to follow, so why do you want to waste your resources on too high update rates? Technically it might be worth looking at the AnimationTimer class to drive the updates. In contrast to Platform.runlater you get some autothrottle for free there.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have tried to reduce the frequency to 60Hz, but the problem of tableview stagnation still occurs when chart points are too many. How to solve this problem

Comment: Do you really think that anybody can read a table which is updated at a rate of 60 Hz? Did you try the AnimationTimer?

Comment: I have tried according to what you said, there is no significant effect when the TableView uses the AnimationTimer, and Chart uses the AnimationTimer. It will have an obvious effect, but I see that the data is significantly less than before, that is to say, the background loses a lot of data by default

Comment: I did not say to throw away all the data. I just said don't update the table/chart that often.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I don't know how to implement it. If you use the animationTimer, there will be a problem of losing data